# Why does this use of fscanf cause the application to crash?

Tags: c, windows, scanf

New to C programming.

The following section of code attempts to read a tab-separated list of MD5 (32 chars) and corresponding description (up to 128 chars) from a text file (utf-8), but is causing the application to crash:

```
HANDLE hFile = CreateFileW(good_path, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL,
    OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, NULL);
if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    return FALSE;
}

LPWSTR md5 = malloc(sizeof(wchar_t) * 32);
LPWSTR desc = malloc(sizeof(wchar_t) * 128);
int i;
while((i = fwscanf(hFile, L"%ls %ls", md5, desc)) != EOF)
{
    if (i == 2) // OK
    {
    }
    else // Something went wrong
    {
    }
}
CloseHandle(hFile);
return TRUE;
```

Few questions:

1. Is my use of malloc(...) correct?
2. What might be causing the crash?

**Update 1**

I've taken this code and made it into a standalone exe (rather than a DLL). Still crashes.

**Update 2**

Updated to fwscanf as per Chris's comment. Still crashes. If I comment out the `while...fwscanf...` line it exits properly.

Comment: What error does it crash with? That's important.

Comment: The code is for a DLL which is a plugin. The hosting application reports "An exception of type 216 occurred at offset 180002F (relative error offset 2FBC)"

Comment: Is this a Unicode file? I ask because I notice you use `%ls` and `wchar_t`. This [article from Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb5kac8b.aspx) states "`fscanf` doesn't currently support input from a UNICODE stream" and advises using `fwscanf` instead.

Comment: Thanks @chrisaycock - good spot. It's a utf-8 file - if I swap for `fwscanf` same problem.

Comment: Debugging this might give more clues as to what's going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CreateFileW()` returns a Windows handle, which is sort of like a file number but different somehow. `fwscanf()` expects a `FILE*` not a Windows handle; to get a `FILE*` open your file with `fopen()` or `_wfopen()`.

Comment: This is great! To be in keeping with the rest of the project I should perhaps find the Microsoft equivalent to `fwscanf`for when the file is opened with CreateFileW().

Answer (score 0):

1. %s stores a null terminator. Malloc 33 and 129 chars.

Comment: Thanks, good spot. Although I do need to correct that, it doesn't seem to be that causing the crash.

Answer (score 0):

%s stores a nul-terminated string under the address your provide. To store n significant characters without buffer overflow, you need to provide an address of n+1 long buffer.

Comment: Thanks, good spot. Although I do need to correct that, it doesn't seem to be that causing the crash.